# c# project simple calculator

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a very simple calculator in C# Visual Express 2013. I am following a book. First week coder here.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/calculator1.txt

In the code written above I do not understand one piece of code:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = true;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;

    txtDisplay.Clear();
}
```

What is the added value of having these booleans here? Is only writing `txtDisplay.Clear();` not enough for the `btnClear_Click` to perform behaviour of a calculator?

Comment: Looks like all should be set to false because that is the default state of the calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the EQUALS BUTTON :

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (plusButtonClicked == true) {
            total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (minusButtonClicked == true) {
            total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true) {
            total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
        else if (divideButtonClicked == true) {
            total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }

        txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString();
        total1 = 0;
    }
```

The developer wants to know if the user clicked on equal button , what should the program do .... just like a real calculator.
But for the clear button **All of the flags should be set to `false`.**

Answer (score 2):

I think everything should be reset to false. so that means even `divideButtonClicked` should be false. Only writing code `txtDisplay.Clear()` will just clear textboxes. We need to clear all the operations all and hence we need to set everything to false

Answer (score 2):

Think of a case if you go in btnClear_Click() then do btnEquals_Click(). It will throw exception for "Input string is not valid for" in line `total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);`

So you need to set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

All of the flags need to be set to false as this is a reset button and therefore you want to make all the other buttons set to their off state (e.g. clicking the divide button switches it to its on state - we need to reset the calculator so now we turn it to the off state)